# ValueError: unknown url type

Tags: python, parsing, urllib2, urllib, traceback

The title pretty much says it all. Here's my code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen as getpage
print = getpage("www.radioreference.com/apps/audio/?ctid=5586")
```

and here's the traceback error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/**/Dropbox/Dev/ComServ/citetest.py", line 2, in <module>
    contents = getpage("www.radioreference.com/apps/audio/?ctid=5586")
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 121, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 366, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 241, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: www.radioreference.com/apps/audio/?ctid=5586
```

My best guess is that urllib can't retrieve data from untidy php URLs. if this is the case, is there a work around? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first try to add `'http://'` in front of the url. Also, do ***not*** store the results in `print`, as **it is binding the reference to another (non callable) object**.

So this line should be:

```
page_contents = getpage("http://www.radioreference.com/apps/audio/?ctid=5586")
```

This returns a file like object. To read its contents you need to use different file manipulation methods, like this:

```
for line in page_contents.readlines():
    print line
```

Comment: Thank you. Not only did you answer my question, you answered my next! ;)

Comment: I have the same error and I have downloaded the website with `wget`, how can I open that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a full URL: ie it must begin with `http://`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `http://www.radioreference.com/apps/audio/?ctid=5586` and it'll work fine.

```
In [24]: from urllib2 import urlopen as getpage

In [26]: print getpage("http://www.radioreference.com/apps/audio/?ctid=5586")
<addinfourl at 173987116 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xa5eb6ac>>
```